# An ignorance - dictionaries claim it is only mass noun/uncountable

Tags: grammar, articles

Checking Oxford and MacMillan dictionaries, "ignorance" is listed as a mass noun. The same in the Cambridge dictionary. However, there is a sentence from the Cambridge English Corpus:

> Is this merely anodyne or does it reflect an ignorance of the medieval equity jurisdictions ?

Also, when I google "an ignorance", I get quite a lot of hits in various documents etc.
Is that a mistake? As no dictionary I consulted allow this to be used in singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an uncountable noun like **sugar**, you can refer to a particular type of sugar using the indefinite article:

> fructose is **a** sugar

In your sentence, **an ignorance** refers to a particular type of ignorance- that of "the medieval equity jurisdictions".

This is different to ignorance in general which, as an uncountable noun, does not require an article, as in the proverb

> ignorance is bliss